# Add span for each letter, but avoid html tags using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I have a string

```
var string = "Selected<br>Works"
```

From which I need to wrap each letter with `<span></span>`, avoiding wrapping the `<br>` tag within span. Is it possible with regex?

I made it to:

```
'Selected<br>Works'.replace(/\S/g, '<span class="letter">$&</span>')
```

Which returns:

```
<span class="letter">S</span>
<span class="letter">e</span>
<span class="letter">l</span>
<span class="letter">e</span>
<span class="letter">c</span>
<span class="letter">t</span>
<span class="letter">e</span>
<span class="letter">d</span>
<span class="letter">&lt;</span>
<span class="letter">b</span>
<span class="letter">r</span>
<span class="letter">&gt;</span>
<span class="letter">W</span>
<span class="letter">o</span>
<span class="letter">r</span>
<span class="letter">k</span>
<span class="letter">s</span>
```

While desired result is:

```
<span class="letter">S</span>
<span class="letter">e</span>
<span class="letter">l</span>
<span class="letter">e</span>
<span class="letter">c</span>
<span class="letter">t</span>
<span class="letter">e</span>
<span class="letter">d</span>
<br>
<span class="letter">W</span>
<span class="letter">o</span>
<span class="letter">r</span>
<span class="letter">k</span>
<span class="letter">s</span>
```

Other string examples are:

- `Art Direction<br>Creative Concept<br>UX/UI Design`
- `Digital Branding<br>Website`

Comment: Each letter or each word?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: Also please multiple examples of input and output expected.

Comment: @kinduser, yes, every letter

Comment: What are you doing with the returned string, I'm assuming it's being appended to the document?

Comment: @DavidThomas Those strings are returned from an object, that I'm using inside pug (jade) to pre-render HTML.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `replace` with a lookahead kind of regular expression:

```js
var string = "Selected<br>Works",
    result = string.replace(/(?![^<]*>)[^<]/g, c => `<span>${c}</span>\n`);

console.log(result);
```

This will also skip other tags, like `<p>` or `</canvas>`. Still, it will not be able to cope with more complex HTML (including scripts, comments, ...), for which regular expressions are not suitable.

Comment: excellent! works almost perfectly, except that I need to find a way to keep `<br>` :/ tag

Comment: It is there. Did you run the snippet?

Comment: Works perfect when I remove the \n. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can split string by `<br>` delimiter that return multiple array contain letters. Then use `.map()` and `.replace()` to wrapping every letter in `<span></span>`. At the end join arrays by `<br>`

```js
var string = "Selected<br>Works";
var newStr = string.split("<br>").map(function(val){
  return val.replace(/(\S)/g, "<span>$1</span>");
}).join("<br>");

console.log(newStr);
document.body.innerHTML = (newStr);
```

```css
span:nth-child(even) {color: blue}
span:nth-child(odd) {color: red}
```

Comment: @Toto If i split string by all tags, i can't join arrays by relevant tag and all tags will be deleted

Comment: My bad , sorry.